# Eclipse Content Assist is Appending Class Name to Variable Suggestions

Tags: java, eclipse

Content Assist in Eclipse Juno is appending the Class name of variables to suggestions. For example, if I start to type:

```
private String firstName
```

and hit Return, Eclipse changes this to:

```
private String firstNameString;
```

I don't know if this is specific to Juno or if I accidentally turned this 'feature' on, but it is really annoying. Any idea how to get rid of this?

Comment: The variable name changes automatically when you hit "return" or "ctrl + space"?

Comment: It occurs both when I hit return or when I hit ctrl+space.

Comment: If this is Java, shouldn't you be ending the name with a , or ; character anyway?  What happens when you do?

Comment: Yes, ending with a semi-colon, comma, or space all give the same unwanted completion. Answer by mabbas fixes it.

Comment: This is still a problem in 2018-12 and M.Abba's answer doesn't fix it if I end with a space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how to resolve the problem when you hit `Return` (because i can't reproduce the issue), but here is the solution to tell eclipse to not modify the variable name automatically when you hit `ctrl + space`:

In eclipse: Select **Window** -> **Preferences** -> **Java** -> **Editor** -> **Content Assist**

uncheck "**Insert single prposals automatically**".

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This problem only seems to occur if you changed the `Auto activation triggers for Java` setting to e.g. `._abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ`, which'll make the Content Assist (almost) always pop up, even without pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

As nitind mentioned, typing a variable name should always end in a comma, semi-colon or space but pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> should be okay. There's a new setting that was added in Eclipse 2018-12 and makes it a bit less annoying (mentioned in the comments below the [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=378588)):

In `Window - Preferences - Java - Editor - Content Assist` tick the `Disable insertion triggers except 'Enter'` box.

With this setting enabled, Content Assist is still going to trigger (depending on the other settings) but you have to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to accept a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In the Spring Tool Suite got to **Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Content Assist** then-
check the option "Disable insertion triggers except 'Enter'. "